# Upload music via API

Tags: deezer

***Is there possible to download music from PC/internet into [Deezer](http://www.deezer.com/) via API?*** I've a quick look to their doc but didn't found how to do that. If not, can someone suggest a social music network with music upload API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is provided for now to upload music into Deezer through the API, that's why there is no documentation. You have to pass through the website, sorry.

Comment: what does `track/{track_id}` put request from http://developers.deezer.com/api/actions-post? Does it update some metadata of the track?

Comment: As said here http://developers.deezer.com/api/track#actions, it updates informations about personnal tracks you uploaded via the website.

Comment: Too bad... The website and desktop app are really not convenient to upload music. I totally understand it's not a priority feature for you, that's the reason why you should let other developers (us) do this job for you. Can't wait to have access to mp3 upload..